# Add query param to url in the Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to add a parameter to the `url` from the route Controller?

For example, my URL is: **myshop.com/order-finished**

And his method controller is:

```
getOrderFinished() {
  // I want add this param
  myshop.com/order-finished?order_number=W00034335
}
```

I want the final URL to be: **myshop.com/order-finished?order_number=W00034335**, but I must add the parameter `order_number` from the controller method.

EDIT: no redirections, please.

Comment: yes it is possible, use redirects

Comment: rewrite rule will help you do so.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add a param to the url from the route Controller?

**Yes**, it is possible.
You can redirect route if you want to go to that url. Say the route name is '**order-finished**' then in the controller you can do the following :

```
return redirect()->route('order-finished', ['order_number'=>'W00034335']);
```

The implication is that the order_number will be appended as a query parameter to that route.

> PS: This answer goes specifically if you are referring to a request call to a route, and not the general url configuration of your app.

Comment: And to generate a new url with parameters use :

`url('route', ['order_number'=>'W00034335']);` ;)

Comment: its will not be correct to do this, there is a behaviour that it gives you the second parameter's array value as a path parameter to the url, so the above example gives..`somepage.com/route/W00034335`

Answer (score 1):

Simply, use `redirect()->to()` method.

```
public function getOrderFinished(){

    // your parameter value

    $param = W00034335;

    return redirect()->to('myshop.com/order-finished?order_number='.$param);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


$paramData = 'W00034335';
return Redirect::to('/order-finished?order_number='. $paramData);
```

Hope this help for you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Since all (or most) of the answers are using redirects, I'll try something else. I feel like this is a very clean approach.

In your routes/web.php file, insert this:

```
Route::get('order/{id}', 'OrderController@show');
```

And then in your OrderController, have this:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);

        return view('orders.show')->with('order', $order);
    }
```

It's the basic idea of routing, as you can find in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing).

Modify the naming conventions how you will!

Answer (score 1):

Use the request illuminate class.

```
$url = 'http://localhost';
$qs = [
   'par1' => 'val1',
   'par2' => 'val2',
];

$url = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create($url)->fullUrlWithQuery($qs);
```

The above code will return `http://localhost?par1=val1&par2=val2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
redirect('order-finished?order_number=W00034335');
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a parameter  to the url you need to define in route file

```
<?php 
Route::get('/order-finished/order_number/{id}', [
                'as' => 'front.order.detail',
                'uses' => 'OrderController@getOrderDetail'
            ]);
{{ route('front.order.detail',$order['id']) }}
?>
```